# A single div element destroys my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, html, position

I am trying to set up a wordpress site well I am putting it together. After adding a slider I wanted to add a single grey line under it but i completely messed up the whole site.

I added it in a div like this in the home page's code (index.php):

```
<div id="line" class="line" style="width:1000px;height:5px;background:#ccc;margin-left:8px;"/>
```

This pushed my sidebar to the middle of the page and messed up my footer, I tried to change the positioning of this div but it didn't help, also it wast the problem that it was too long and it just overlapped the sidebars div.

Maybe this is just me putting the div in the wrong place, but I can not figure it out.

The site is http://www.enyx.sk

I appreciate any help thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use "self-closing" `div`s in HTML, the `/>` isn't interpreted as a closing tag by the browser. So you end up with just opening a `div`, never closing it again.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5) for reference.